# query execution performance issues with a NOT IN in where clause

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query such

```
SELECT SOME_FILEDS FROM MY_VIEW
```

`MY_VIEW` is  a view retrieving data from other views, it takes 45 minutes to execute a query from `MY_VIEW` on a production server.

By trying to invesetigate the problem i realized that one sub-view is slow.

I know that creating many views is not the best pactice but this is a constraint i must stick to.

The culprit (=slow) view is like this:

```
CREATE VIEW V_SLOW_VIEW
AS
SELECT     MAX(MAIN_ID), ANOTHER_ID
FROM         V_DETAIL_VIEW
WHERE     (MAIN_ID NOT IN -- NOT IN!!!
                          (SELECT     MAIN_ID
                            FROM          ANOTHER_SIMPLE_KEYVALUE_VIEW))
GROUP BY ANOTHER_ID
```

i noticed that by commenting the `WHERE` condition this `V_SLOW_VIEW` becomes faster and `MY_VIEW` has an acceptable execution time. So somehot the `NOT IN` gives a problem.

**Final note**: the same db copied on another (developement) machine behaves normally and querying `MY_VIEW` is painless and fast (2 seconds vs 45 minutes).

I tried also to install another sql server instance, i discussed the problem [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54317/installing-sql-server-express-in-parallel-of-standard)

So somehow this problem is related to one single production server anyway i would like to understand why a `NOT IN` command can generate such a performance problem.

Comment: Can you compare the execution plans on the server where it's slow and fast?

Comment: Have you try with [SQL Server Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)?

Comment: @Szymon I compared the execution plans and they are identical, minor differences like Sort 24% vs 27% but overall they are the same

Comment: Amount of data is the same? Have you tried to update statistics before running the queries?

Comment: @Szymon dbs are the same, so same data. update statistics works on views?

Comment: Not sure, rather on underlying tables.

Comment: @Szymon Just to be sure i recompared the dbs and now also on my machine it is slow, i was comparing (my fault) 2 different versions (=same schema, different data). I will run the execution plan on the query on the main view and see if i find a bottlenck, it is very hard to debug since it takes 45 minutes to have a result (at least on the customer super pc).

Comment: @Szymon I thimnk the problem is using non indexed views. my NOT IN statement runs against non indexed ids. I will try by using real tables instead of views. I could also use indexed views but it is something i never tried and so i will go for tables

Comment: So is the problem solved this way? Interested to know.

Comment: @Szymon yes, problem solved. I will answer my own qusetion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in non use of indexed view I suppose, since i had to do this as fast as i could i didn't experiment with indexed views (something I know it exists but i never used) but simply made a `TABLE` and a stored procedure to load that table with the data that should go in one view and then a `DELETE` at the end.

So the `NOT IN` was working very slow because of lack of index i suppose.